# shadows on wrong side of normals

Tags: normal-map

I have this simple set up of cubes and planes with a texture, all of my normals face out but for some reason some of my them don't react to the lighting and shadow as they should:
[image]
for them to look correct I'll have to flip the normals to face toward inside, I can't find what's the reason and it don't look like having a logical pattern to it, some faces look weird at random.
I suspect my normal map, can somebody explain what's wrong with my normal map and what a proper normal map should look like please?http://sta.sh/01py369pouw3
I've changed my normal map to a proper one but looks like the problem is rooted somewhere else
[image]
does anybody have any idea what's wrong? http://sta.sh/01n0s48c9prn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was the non-color data I had to select for my normal maps image
[image]

considering how often it's mentioned in tutorials/videos I wonder why nobody bothered to check it and tell me

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your normal map. Somehow all the pixels that are white in the brick diffuse texture appear to be Transparent in your normal map.

[image]

I have no idea what was going on with the end part of your wall that wasn't showing shadow in your original image but after remodelling it from a basic cube it seemed to be working as expected.